Singularity structure being valid for all QFTs?
I'm trying to understand this paper in which the authors try to build a wavefunction for the universe without assuming locality and unitarity, so they would be rather emergent from geometrical constructs called "polytopes" and not assumed from the start (they tried to do the same with Lorentz invariance as well)
In the abstract it's said that the singularity structure of the toy model for the wavefunction of the universe that they used is universal and valid for all theories. Later, near the end (page 65) it says that again. Also, they say in page 56 that the geometric framework to compute the wavefunction of the universe doesn't make any reference to the underlying theory.
I get that the singularities they are talking about refer to the poles found in correlators in quantum field theories (although they would be referring to cosmological correlators instead, as the paper is intended to apply to cosmology) and that they would be universal in the sense that correlators in any quantum field theory will have these singularities
However, what do the authors mean saying that it would be valid for all theories being universal for all of them or that they do not make any reference to the underlying theory?. I mean, do they only refer to all possible QFTs? Or are they referring more generally to the possible fundamental theories that could describe the universe (i.e. quantum gravity theories or theories of everything like string theory)?
For instance, in these presentations (A Timeless History of Time & Bootstrapping large graviton non-Gaussianity by Enrico Pajer), in the context of the cosmological bootstrap program, which is related to the previous papers, it is indicated that physicists could use the cosmological singularity correlators to study correlators from UV-complete theories, non-perturbative QFT and modified theories of gravity. Does it mean then that all possible theories of fundamental high energy physics could be studied in this framework through these singularity correlators?
